# Кэширование изображений

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется вот [такая вещь](http://gtp4all.ru/voltmeter/). "Внутри" около 70 изображений, которые первоначально:

```
display: none
```

Если включить прибор, видно (на Opera, Firefox), как изображения "подгружаются" (display: inline). Если сразу выключить-включить устройство, то видно, что изображения уже не "подгружаются", а появляются моментально. Загрузить всё изначально в кэш - подумал я. Попробовал несколько методов из интернета для кэширования изображений - не помогло. После полной загрузки страницы сделал так:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

У каждого изображения имеется нужная src. В чём проблема? Почему картинки подгружаются не сразу? Может и не в кэше дело?

P.S. Причём [здесь](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/displayimg.html) Mozilla Firefox подгружает картинки немедленно

Comment: Что интересно, мне на другом сайте нужно как-то побороть именно загрузку изначально в кэш и именно на Firefox) И да, в приведённом примере у меня тоже все картинки загружаются и кэшируются до включения устройства.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и не смог увидить описаный тобой эффект.. Если у тебя проблеммы с кешированием (если я правильно понял твою проблемму) - попробуй сделать предзагрузчик

```
  var $img = $("img");
  var total = $img.length, loaded = 0;//Сколько всего и сколько загруженно
  var onLoad = function(){}//Это то, что будет вып-ся по окончании загрузки (убирается заглушка "Загрузка..." или еще что-то в таком духе и начинает все работать)
  $img.each(function() {
      var img=new Image();
      img.src=this.src;
      img.onload=function(){
          loaded++;//+1 к загруженным
          if(loaded == total){onLoad();}//Если все загрузилось - то запускаем 
      } 
 });
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Т.е. у Вас подобного эффекта не наблюдается?

Comment: Во всяком случае, никаких проблем с картинками я не увидел. М.б., конечно, у меня интернет тут достаточно быстрый